# Calculate on Previous Value

Tags: crystal-reports, report

```
Opening           Installment                Balance

5000              1000                        4000
4000              1000                        3000
3000              1000                        2000
2000              1000                        1000
1000              1000                        0
```

How to do this Output in Crystal Report XI R2?
I have only two Fields Only "Opening" and "Installment"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Previous() function to compare the current row to the prior row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing a SQL datasource, I suggest you do it in SQL instead.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. Can you include your existing query, and which variety of SQL (MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle, etc.) and which version of Crystal you are using, in your question?

Comment: select Asset.AMT_FINANCED,Flow_Calc.AMOUNT from flow_Calc,Asset where flow_Calc.Asset_id=Asset.Asset_ID and Using Crystal Report XI R2 Version